# Fullcalendar Event Color not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I pass the resource color to the fullcalendar. According to the documentation if I render a event it should be displayed with the color that I passed to the resource earlier. Strangly this is not the case for me.

This is what I pass to the fullcalendar as a resource

```
"id" => "erna46"
"title" => "erna46"
"eventColor" => "rgb(45,0,255)"
"eventTextColor" => "rgb(255,255,255)"
```

Now in my fullcalendar the event is rendered with the color `rgb(98,64,255)`

I am not sure if this is normal or not and if so is there a way to turn color change off?

**Update:**

Here is a JSFidle to show the problem:

http://jsbin.com/pofemef/edit?js,output

As you can see i set the color e.g. rgb(255,147,0) but in the calendar it is displayed as rgb(255,174,64).

Comment: It should work with eventColor or eventBackgroundColor.  Check once again if the input to eventColor is set properly

Comment: I checked the eventColor and it is rgb(45,0,255) but still it is displyed as rgb(98,64,255)

Comment: I also just tried to repruduce this in the json demo and same result there

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I added a jsfidle link to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @DanielSchwarz looks fine to me. The computed background colour of each event has an RGB value which matches what you specified in the corresponding resources entry. And you can see the style property of the element where it was injected by fullCalendar. http://imgur.com/a/PW04l

Comment: @ADyson but how come that it is not the same color in the color picker, doesen't make sense to me http://imgur.com/a/SQcTJ

Comment: @DanielSchwarz what browser are you using? And is the colour picker some sort of plugin? I would suggest that, given the evidence I've shown, that the the "colour picker" software is more likely to have a bug in it. The values shown in the actual HTML and CSS will be the correct ones.

Comment: @ADyson I updated the JSFiddle once again to insert some text with the same background color as the appointment. As you can clearly see the color is different. I am also certain that the color picker is working fine. For your information I am using Firefox 51.1.0.1 but I also tested it with chrome and same result there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some work i figured it out. By default the appointment will add a background above the appointment with background: #fff and opacity: .25 . This will change the color off the appointment so it appears lighter than the set appointment color.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zolnh.jpg

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventColor/), eventColor property sets the background and border colors for *all* events on the calendar, not each event separately. So if you declare an event like this:

```
events: [{
        title: 'event',
        start: '2017-01-05 11:00',
        end: '2017-01-06 13:00',
        eventColor: 'rgb(45,0,255)'
        }]
```

It's not gonna work. You can use eventColor for every event:

```
events: [{
        title: 'event',
        start: '2017-01-05 11:00',
        end: '2017-01-06 13:00'
        }],
eventColor: '#378006'
```

If you want to change the color for individual events, please look at the [Event Object color options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/Event_Object/#color-options)

```
events: [{
        title: 'event',
        start: '2017-01-05 11:00',
        end: '2017-01-06 13:00',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,87,90)'
        }]
```

Comment: I do not try to set the event color directly. I pass the event color with my resoureces. Then i pass the resourceId with my events. This in theory works and is also shown in the demos of fullcalendar. The strange thing is that even when i pass the right color it is not displayed correctly.